# How to show that the banana function is positive semi-definite, and explain why it still is not convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

<sub>[I've asked this question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204140/why-is-rosenbrocks-banana-function-not-convex-over-a-positive-semi-definite-hes/3204264#3204264), but the answers just made me even more confused.</sub>

---

> Consider Rosenbrock’s (modified) Banana Function
>
> $$f(x,y) = 36(y − x^2)^2 + (x − 1)^2$$
>
> Show that the Hessian of this function is positive semidefinite in the region $y \leq x^2 + \frac{1}{72}$ . Explain why the function is not convex in this region.

I have found the Hessian to be

$$H(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} -144(y-x^2)+288x^2+2 & -144x\\ -144x & 72\end{bmatrix}$$

I had the idea to apply inequality at the beginning to $f(x,y)$, which gave eigenvalues $0$ and $2$, showing positive semidefiniteness. I have also tried applying on the Hessian only, which gave the result $0$ and $72+288x^2$, which also shows positive semidefiniteness. Apparently this doesn't work. I have absolutely no idea how to explain why it isnt convex in the region though, as we have only been taught that positive semidefiniteness implies convexity.

We haven't had anything similiar in class. We aren't even past quadratic, let alone quartics, and when I tried to simply sub in the inequality, someone said that you cannot do that. I do not know how to answer this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It would be good that you show the ideas you have on the question. You can start to update the question with your computation of the Hessian.

Comment: The region $y \le x^2 + \frac{1}{72}$ is not convex. I'm not even sure what it means for a function to be convex on a non-convex domain.

Comment: @TheoBendit the question wants to show it is positive semi-definite but also explain why its not convex. Can you explain your reasoning for it being a non-convex domain please :)

Comment: Well, just plot it! The curve $y = x^2 + \frac{1}{72}$ is an upwards-opening parabola, and the region $y \le x^2 + \frac{1}{72}$ is everything below it, which is clearly not convex. More explicitly, consider the points $(-1, \frac{73}{72})$ and $(1, \frac{73}{72})$, both in the region, but the midpoint, $(0, \frac{73}{72})$ is not in the region.

Comment: @TheoBendit YES I have been looking for an answer like this for so long. So simple, but is literally the proof. A function cannot be convex on a non-convex set, as the definition of a convex function cannot be satisfied for all x in D(f). Thank you, I never saw it before now.

Comment: @PatrickChristie Ah, glad I could be of service!